# Как парсить публичные каналы Telegram без бота/авторизации?

Tags: telegram

Веб-каталоги каналов Telegram показывают список последних сообщений на странице описания каждого конкретного канала.
Вопрос: каким образом это можно реализовать?
И можно ли это сделать в клиентском приложении, без использования сложных веб-сервисов?